# Sharepoint Content Query Webpart from content type with additional columns shows empty slots and not all data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, content-query-web-part

i have a strange problem with CQWP

I have a list contenttype that is assigned to some lists.
Now I want to use a content query webpart to show all items with additional columns based on this content type.

What I have done so far:

1. I have created a custom itemsytyle.xsl file
2. I have added my custom columns into this xsl file.
   [image]
3. I have checked in the new file as major version
4. I have created a content query webpart with the following query:
   Listtype = user defined list
   Contenttype = My Contenttype
5. I have exported this webpart and added my columns to CommonViewFields. The field typing and data type are correct when i checked it from the url param (fid=....) in the edit section of the content type 
   Vertragsbeginn, DateTime;Vertragsende, DateTime;Vertragsart, Text
6. I have added the new itemstyle to the webpart.
   /team/vm/Style%20Library/XSL%20Style%20Sheets/CustomItemStyle.xsl
7. I have set the cache param to false in the webpart file ( in case it is a Cache issue)
8. I have uploaded the new webpart
9. I delete the old webpart and add the new just generated webpart

My problems now are:

- The slots in the display section will not shown. There are always the default slots with title, description, .... when i choose my custom style.
  [image]
- The values of the addtional columns are not displayed in my CQWP only the Titles from the different lists that are assigned to this content type . [image]

  Only when i switch the source of the webpart directly to a list that is assigned to this content type all the values will be displayed.[image]

i have also created an item style to Display all fields. When i checked this i didn´t found my fields that i have added to the commonviewfields
[image]

i´ve have already looked into so many good Topics regarding this Topic in this board and on Google without any success.

Has anybody an idea how to solve this?